# Setting request.session causes HTTP 500 Error when posting form to Django

Tags: django

Even setting session to simple string changes http response from status 200 to 500.  The httml button has id="requestquote".
**Webpage javascript:**

```
$('#requestquote').click(function(){
    var jpicks = JSON.stringify(picks);
    $.post("requestforquote",{counties:jpicks}).done(function(){
        window.location = BASE_URL + "countyparcels/quoteform"
    });
});
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(requestforquote)$',views.request4quote),
    url(r'^(quoteform)$',views.quoteform)
]
```

**views.py**

```
SHOPPING_CART = 'shoppingcart'

@csrf_exempt
def request4quote(request,misc):
    try:
        request.session[SHOPPING_CART] = request.POST['counties']  # No    exception here
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
    try:
        response = HttpResponse("True",content_type="text/plain")  # No exception here
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
        response = Http404
    return response  # Get HTTP: 500  if I include session setting code above
        # I get the error even is session set to simple string literal ... like "true"
```

Comment: Where is `response` defined? What is you full error message?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I hadn't synced my database. I did not have, amoung other things, the authentication and session tables. Doing the following fixed the problem:

```
python migrate.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring in your response variable value.
You are returning the `Http404` type object in your exception, this will raise an `AttributeError`, so it's an exception leading to another exception.

From the code you provided above the only thing i can think of is that you didn't import 
`HttpResponse`.
You need to :
`from django.http import HttpResponse`

if this doesn't work you ll need to provide the traceback.

Comment: I'm not getting a stack trace other than the following:
[03/Oct/2015 08:19:49]"POST /countyparcels/requestforquote HTTP/1.1" 500 16007.
To be clear, its simply adding the line of code "
request.session[SHOPPING_CART] = request.POST['counties'] "
that results the  internal error when the response is returned.  There is no exception at the request.session[SHOPPING_CART] assignment - (ie the "except" is not executed).

Comment: is your $.post posting to your view? try printing request.POST and see if counties is there

Comment: Yes. The request.POST['counties'] has the county json data.

Comment: try ``request.session[SHOPPING_CART] =json.loads(request.POST['counties'])``, make sure you ``import json``

Comment: also replace ``response = Http404`` with ``raise Http404``

Comment: Here is the code with your suggestions:
    
    def request4quote(request,misc):
       try:
            request.session[SHOPPING_CART] = json.loads(request.POST['counties'])
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
        request.session[SHOPPING_CART] = {}
        try:
            response = HttpResponse("True",content_type="text/plain")
        except Exception as e:
            print e.message
            raise Http404
        return response